# Draw scheme for algorithm

Tags: pylons, draw, diagram, graph-algorithm, dia

What program is modeled in [this](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.2-branch/_images/resourcetreetraverser.png) diagram?

Comment: It is more an algorithm than a program, and it is more for explanation than for something else...

Answer (score 1):

According to Pylon's [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html), that's

> The Pyramid traversal algorithm. We’ll provide a description of the algorithm, a diagram of how the algorithm works, and some example traversal scenarios that might help you understand how the algorithm operates against a specific resource tree

In the above link there's a clear [description](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html#a-description-of-the-traversal-algorithm) of the algorithm, and [here](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1.2b3/pyramid/traversal.py) it is the implementation, in Python.